# What are the functionalities of IPython Tasks database?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, mpi, airflow, luigi

Having a look at the doc and Google :
https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db.html

There is little example of the functionalities such as :

```
   Scheduling the tasks to be launched at some time.
   Put an execution order of the tasks.
   Interface to visualize the lisk of tasks.
   Code Source associated with each task (code to be run).
```

There is Luigi and Airflow, but they do not manage the code source for each task. Can IPython task manager be able to manage the scheduling of tasks as well as the code source?

Comment: What do you mean by "manage the code source for each task"?

Comment: Mean each py script inside a task (effective task action) is stored somehere (in DB or on disk).